# How to use getExtras from an intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm new Android and I don't know how to solve this problem: I'm using an intent in the onCreate in order to read NFC tags, and I'm trying to use the text read from the tag.

I manage for the moment to read the tag, and display this text, but only in the method "resolveIntent" (the TextView "tvResponse" shows correctly my data in "resolveIntent", but everywhere else is empty). My problem is I need to use this value in my onCreate method, and I don't know how to get it out from resolveIntent.

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Here is the corresponding section in my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfcpositioning_main);

    mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
    tvResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResponse);


    //TAGS READING 

    resolveIntent(getIntent());     

    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
        finish();
        return;
    }


    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(
            "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true) });

    tvResponse.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("MSG"));
```

and the void "resolveIntent" which is also in the main activity:

```
public void resolveIntent(Intent Xintent) {
    String action = Xintent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = Xintent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {                          
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }

            NdefMessage msg = msgs[0];
            byte[] payload = msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload();  

            String result="";
            for (int b = 3; b<payload.length; b++) {
                result += (char) payload[b];
            }               
            String StringNdefMessagePart = result;

            //tvResponse.setText(StringNdefMessagePart);
            Xintent.putExtra("MSG", StringNdefMessagePart);

        } else {            
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty NFC tag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, but cant you just declare a global variable or return the text after reading it from resolveIntent()?

Answer (score 0):

I leave an example of a personal code, I hope it helps you

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,DetalleEventoActivity.class);                                        
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putLong("IDEV", e.getId());           
                b.putLong("FECHA", e.getFecha());         
                b.putString("NOMBRE_EVENTO", e.getNombreEvento());      
                b.putString("NUMERO_MAQUINA", e.getNroMaquinaDGC());        
                b.putString("SECTOR", e.getSector());       
                b.putString("SOCIO", e.getNroSocio());      
                b.putString("CATEGORIA", e.getCategoriaSocio());        

                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
```

---IN DetalleEventoActivity-------------------------------------------

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    id = bundle.getLong("IDEV");
    fechaLong = bundle.getLong("FECHA");
    fecha = formatter.format(fechaLong);
    nombreEvento = bundle.getString("NOMBRE_EVENTO");
    nroMaquina = bundle.getString("NUMERO_MAQUINA");
    sector = bundle.getString("SECTOR");
    socio = bundle.getString("SOCIO");
    categoria = bundle.getString("CATEGORIA");
```